# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Wrapper)

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

**situation**

- I'm facing this problem after I fixed the [HOC error](https://github.com/taiga-programming/typescript-app/issues/7). I don't know how to add a provider to my App.tsx file base on my redux functionalities.

this is [my repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/typescript-app)

**error**

```
 Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Wrapper)".
   Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom
   React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React
   context consumer to Connect(Wrapper) in connect options.
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from './secure/dashboard/Dashboard';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path={'/'} exact component={RedirectToDashboard} />
        <Route path={'/dashboard'} exact component={Dashboard} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**configureStore.tsx**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import setUserReducer from './reducers/setUserReducer';

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(setUserReducer);
};
```

export default configureStore;

Answer (score 1):

Like the error said, You've to provide your `store` object to `Provider`.

Perhaps in your `index.tsx` file, you've to wrap it like this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import store from './configureStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  // Render a `<Provider>` around the entire `<App>`,
  // and pass the Redux store to as a prop
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

You can refer the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#passing-the-store-with-provider)